# ngModel value in <img src=""> ionic 3

Tags: image, ionic-framework, src

I am trying to implement a weatherforecast in my app. I'm using the danish national weatherforecast servlet. The only thing I have to change is the postal code, which in this case is 8000. I have tried some different things like: src="http://......"+'{{city.postNumber}}'+"...", but that did not work. Any ideas? This might be easy, but I can't figure it out.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="city.postNumber">8000</ion-input>
    <img id="dk_days_two_forecast" 
    src="http://servlet.dmi.dk/byvejr/servlet/byvejr_dag1?by=8000&mode=long"
    alt="Weather forecast"/>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

I know there is missing a script for actually changing the value, but city.postNumber is set to 8000 in .ts.

```
export class WeatherPage {
  city = {postNumber:"8000"};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
```

Comment: when do you want to update img, on blur or on keypress?

Comment: Hi. I want to update the image on button click. I can easily change the variable by buttonclick, but I don't know how to include this variable in the src. Right now it's just 8000, but how do I get my own city.postNumber in there?@SwapnilPatwa

Comment: Check answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this- [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5vZA8y?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary">Post Number</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="city.postNumber"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <button ion-button block (click)="refresh()">Get</button>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <img [src]="imgSrc" alt="Weather forecast" />
  </ion-item>
```

**TS:**

```
  city:any = {postNumber:"8000"};
  imgSrc:any=`http://servlet.dmi.dk/byvejr/servlet/byvejr_dag1?by=${this.city.postNumber}&mode=long`

  constructor(public navController: NavController) { }
  refresh () {
    this.imgSrc = `http://servlet.dmi.dk/byvejr/servlet/byvejr_dag1?by=${this.city.postNumber}&mode=long`
  }
```

Comment: And great idea to construct the string in ts. Did not think about that. :-D

Comment: Glad to hear that.